# What Index can I apply to a GROUP BY, MIN() and WHERE MySQL Query

Tags: mysql, performance, index-tuning, query-performance

I have the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE `wp_prize_draws_log_copy` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `pid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `entry_date` date NOT NULL,
  `entry_time` datetime NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `ip` varchar(15) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `user_agent` text NOT NULL,
  `lead_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `first_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `last_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `telephone` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `postcode` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `optin` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `third_optin` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `result` enum('OK','DUPE','BANNED','IP_LIMITED') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'OK',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=189370 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

And I need to do the following query on it:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM (
    SELECT MIN(`id`) as `first_id`
    FROM `wp_prize_draws_log_copy`
    WHERE `result` = "OK" AND `optin` = 1
    GROUP BY `email`
) as `f`
INNER JOIN `wp_prize_draws_log_copy` AS `pdl`
    ON `pdl`.`id` = `f`.`first_id`
WHERE `pid` = %d AND `optin` = 1
```

This query gives me the number of optins that we the first ever of a given prize but the query takes 5+ seconds with the inner query taking in the region of 3+ seconds.

I've tried adding indexes but with no success of speeding up the query.

What indexes can I apply to the table to speed this query, if any? Or can this query be written differently to speed it up?

Comment: An index on `(result, optin, email, id)` would suffice I think. The query is fine, but you can remove the `AND optin = 1` from the external query.

Comment: This brought the query time down to a little over 1 second which is much improved. Do you want to put your comment as an answer?